# Capturing the entire webpage with WebExecute's "CapturePage"

Tags: webdriver

It seems that `"CapturePage"` in `WebExecute` only captures the currently visible portion of a website:

[image]

Is there some way to capture the whole image of a `WebSessionObject`? Or to print it to PDF?

Comment: In case anybody else is checking, `WebImage` just uses `WebExecute["CapturePage"]` under the hood.

Comment: Just a minor note: This is not possible in general, since many web pages have dynamic behavior, including behavior which loads more data when a web page is scrolled down to the 'end'. This sort of infinite scrolling prevents you from taking a 'full screenshot' of any page.

Comment: You can automate scrolling

Comment: @M.R. How do you automate scrolling?  I didn't see it in the documentation.

Comment: @kickert I don’t know, this never really worked for me

Answer (score 15):

The WebExecute framework uses functions specified by the [W3C WebDriver spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/). Unfortunately, the "Screenshot" functionality doesn't *specifically* allow for taking a screenshot of the entire page - just the viewport.

However, you can do this, provided you set the browser to headless mode (that is, pass `Visible->False` when you start your web session), getting the document height and setting the window height to it.

```
session = StartWebSession["Chrome", Visible -> False];

WebExecute["OpenPage" -> "https://toughsoles.ie"]

WebExecute["SetWindowSize" -> {600, WebExecute["JavascriptExecute" -> "return document.body.scrollHeight"]}]

WebExecute["CapturePage"]

(* Output is full Image of the web page *)
```

The crucial parts here are:

1. Start your session with `Visible->False`
2. Get the optimum window height with `WebExecute["JavascriptExecute" -> "return document.body.scrollHeight"]`
3. Set the viewport height with `SetWindowSize` - you might want to vary the width depending on your intended website or use case.

There's a bit of nuance with getting the optimum viewport height that I have not dealt with - [this answer is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147768/4604972).

Comment: In my case I need Visibility -> True, is there a way to force a print to PDF?

Comment: No - at least, not in the WebDriver spec. However, you could call `window.print()` in javascript. You'd still have to navigate the print UI manually, though. That UI is uncontrollable and browser-specific.

Comment: That’s too bad because I needed to use this in combination with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197127/403 @CarlLange

Comment: If you had mentioned that in your question, I could have given you a better answer. This might be possible - You should be able to simply press the "Print to PDF" button in the print dialog using `RobotTools` after calling `window.print()`.