# Capturing complete webimages

Tags: webdriver

I'm trying to use [WebImage[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WebImage.html) to capture the complete image of a website (yes, it might be very tall). I seem to be having some issues with it:

- **How to attempt to capture a complete image of the website?**  Perhaps as a series of up to n screenshots after scrolling n viewports and then `ImageAssemble[]` them together?
- **Other than rate-limiting, how to avoid loading and security issues?**  I want to scrape images of many sites in parallel (and leverage asynchronous operations if possible).

**Examples of these issues:**

```
WebImage["https://www.adidas.com/us/"]
```

[image: shot]

```
WebImage["https://www.adidas.com/us/", Method -> "Chrome"]
```

[image]

```
WebImage["https://www.adidas.com/us/", Method -> "Firefox"]
```

[image]

**Code for #3:**

```
urls={"https://www.adidas.com/us/","https://www.nike.com/","https://www.wikipedia.org","https://www.wolframalpha.com","https://us.puma.com/en/us/men/shoes","https://www.yahoo.com"}; 
SetSharedVariable[urls];
t = Table[ParallelSubmit[{i}, WebImage[RandomChoice[urls]]], {i, 30}]; WaitAll[%] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Firefox has a built-in feature that can take a complete screenshot of the entire web page not just the portion visible on screen. I asked for this feature in a Wolfram live stream and was ignored .

Comment: Anything, even a partial answer would be nice!

Comment: I vaguely remember that it can be done with `WebExecute` by setting either infinite browser window height using `"SetWindowSize"` or making the window full screen with `"WindowFullScreen"`. It may be also necessary to make the window invisible for this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Use chrome in headless mode with screenshot option and try to get it working. It might require to increase the delay if that's possible to ensure the page is fully loaded before the shot is taken. Also, I'm wondering how to determine the right resolution so that the page fit's onto the image, but that's another thing. First off, I would simply start with chrome in the commandline and try to get it working.

Comment: As @Alexey Popkov says, this can be achieved using `WebExecute` and `"SetWindowSize"`. See the answer by @Carl Lange [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197872/41179)

Comment: There is a Chrome extension for this: https://gofullpage.com

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I'll look at that link, but I really need to script this action - so I need a mathematica solution.

Comment: @user5601 Does the answer by Carl Lange linked above work for you? If not, can you elaborate why?

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides No it doesn't work.

Comment: There is a new resource function for this: [FullWebImage](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FullWebImage/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Documentation page [workflow/CaptureAnEntireWebpage](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/CaptureAnEntireWebpage.html) you have detailed answer to your question (note that the browser must be run in headless mode, with `Visible -> False`!):

```
session = StartWebSession["Firefox", Visible -> False];
WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> "https://www.adidas.com/us"];

width = WebExecute[session, 
  "JavascriptExecute" -> "return document.documentElement.scrollWidth"]
height = WebExecute[session, 
  "JavascriptExecute" -> "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"]

WebExecute[session, "SetWindowSize" -> {width, height}]

webpageImage = WebExecute[session, "CapturePage"];
```

Check what is captured:

```
Thumbnail[webpageImage]
ImageTake[webpageImage, -100]
```

[image: screenshot]

As one can see, the bottom of the web page still isn't captured due to insufficient `height`. Increase the height:

```
WebExecute[session, "SetWindowSize" -> {width, height + 800}]
```

Now we get the complete web page:

```
webpageImage = WebExecute[session, "CapturePage"];    
ImageTake[webpageImage, -600]
```

[image: screenshot2]

Use `DeleteObject` to terminate the web session process:

```
DeleteObject[session]
```

P.S. The [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197866/capturing-the-entire-webpage-with-webexecutes-capturepage/197872#comment523532_197866) by [Arnoud Buzing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/105/arnoud-buzing) (the developer of `WebExecute`) under duplicate question explains why it is not possible in general to get the true page height:

> Just a minor note: This is not possible in general, since many web
> pages have dynamic behavior, including behavior which loads more data
> when a web page is scrolled down to the 'end'. This sort of infinite
> scrolling prevents you from taking a 'full screenshot' of any page. –
> Arnoud Buzing  Jul 23 '19 at 18:35

Comment: Can you try this on a much longer page please? Like https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ModularTessellation/ with all the sections expanded?

Comment: @user5601 For expanding the sections one have to write some additional JavaScript code.

Comment: When I test this on a tall website it's not working, see my update.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to work!